# Mobile Safari/Webkit On Window Focus Event

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, mobile-webkit

I am wondering if it is possible to get a event when the user switches back to "your" page's window? This could happen either when the user opens a new tab and then switches back to your page's tab or when the user closes safari and then opens it again.

I want to be able to update content on the page once I get this event. I am using a setInterval to accomplish this now, but it would be nice to not have the delay when the user focuses on your window.

Thanks!

Comment: Now this question was raised exactly two years ago to the date. Does anyone know if there are still no such events?

Answer (score 1):

The chance of this one getting resolved seems small:

I created [this](https://gist.github.com/848902) script to log as many WebKit events as possible (event names taken from http://svn.webkit.org/repository/webkit/trunk/Source/WebCore/dom/EventNames.h), and it doesn't seem to trigger any event upon leaving/bringing to front Safari.

Answer (score 1):

I've been digging around and found that a `focus` event is fired when the window is activated again.

It should be doable like this (using jQuery):

```
$(window).on('focus', function() {
    ...focus code here...
});
```

This event is probably fired more often than needed, but it worked for me.